# JQuery not linking with CSS in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am running some simple code and it will not run on my home machine. I am using the JQuery UI to run an example and even that will not run. I have downloaded the full version of JQuery, and am running it using WAMP/Apache.

The code is as follows :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){

                // Accordion
                $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });

                // Tabs
                $('#tabs').tabs();

                // Datepicker
                $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                    inline: true
                });

                // Slider
                $('#slider').slider({
                    range: true,
                    values: [17, 67]
                });

                // Progressbar
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                    value: 20 
                });

                //hover states on the static widgets
                $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
                    function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
                    function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
                );

            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            /*demo page css*/
            body{ font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}
            .demoHeaders { margin-top: 2em; }
            #dialog_link {padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;text-decoration: none;position: relative;}
            #dialog_link span.ui-icon {margin: 0 5px 0 0;position: absolute;left: .2em;top: 50%;margin-top: -8px;}
            ul#icons {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
            ul#icons li {margin: 2px; position: relative; padding: 4px 0; cursor: pointer; float: left;  list-style: none;}
            ul#icons span.ui-icon {float: left; margin: 0 4px;}

        </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    h1 { padding: .2em; margin: 0; }
    #products { float:left; width: 500px; margin-right: 2em; }
    #cart { width: 200px; float: left; }
    #cart ol { margin: 0; padding: 1em 0 1em 3em; }
    .tooltip {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000;
  color: #000000; outline: none;
  cursor: help; text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip span {
  margin-left: -999em;
  position: absolute;
}

    .tooltip:hover span {
              font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
              position: absolute;
              left: 1em;
              top: 2em;
              z-index: 99;
              margin-left: 0;
              width: 250px;
            }
            .tooltip:hover img {
              border: 0;
              margin: -10px 0 0 -55px;
              float: left;
              position: absolute;
            }
            .tooltip:hover em {
              font-family: Candara, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
              font-size: 1.2em;
              font-weight: bold;
              display: block;
              padding: 0.2em 0 0.6em 0;
            }
            .classic { padding: 0.8em 1em; }
            .custom { padding: 0.5em 0.8em 0.8em 2em; }
            * html li:hover { background: transparent; }
            .classic { background: #FFFFAA; border: 1px solid #FFAD33; }border-radius: 5px 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);


    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#catalog" ).accordion();
        $( "#catalog li" ).draggable({
            appendTo: "body",
            helper: "clone"
        });
        $( "#cart ol" ).droppable({
            activeClass: "ui-state-default",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
            accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
                $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
            }
        }).sortable({
            items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
            sort: function() {
                // gets added unintentionally by droppable interacting with sortable
                // using connectWithSortable fixes this, but doesn't allow you to customize active/hoverClass options
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<div id="products">
    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Products</h1>  
    <div id="catalog">
        <h3><a href="#">Processors</a></h3>
        <div>
            <ul class ="tooltip">
                <a class ="tooltip"><span class="classic">This is just an example of what you can do using a CSS tooltip, feel free to get creative and produce your own!</span>Intel i7</a>
                <li>Intel i5</li>
                <li>Intel i3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Graphics Cards</a></h3>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Nvidia GeForce 9700</li>
                <li>Nvidia 1200GT</li>
                <li>Nvidia GeForce GTX 580</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">Monitors</a></h3>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Acer 15'</li>
                <li>Dell 17'</li>
                <li>Compaq 12'</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="cart">
    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Shopping Cart</h1>
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <ol>
            <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>





</div>


    </body>
</html>
```

When I try and go to localhost and into my file it displays without any CSS or pictures. It will, however, work in my college machine. Both sets of files have the same file structure and are running the same code.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Where are your `html`, `head` and `body` tags? My guess is that your current browser sees this code and gives up when trying to parse it. You're missing `type` attributes on your `style` and `script` tags as well, and the requisite jQuery UI include is missing.

Comment: You're not including jquery with a <script type="javascript" src="path/to/jquery-1.5.js"></script> in this example...

Comment: @can you post your code once again , some important stuff missig..

Comment: Sorry, linked the wrong code. Fixed now.

Comment: Are you both using the same browser (and version)? I suspect it could be the browser refusing to cooperate since there are issues with the mark-up. For example, you have lots of code which should be in the head down in the body (including CSS and meta tags)... If you try to use the same exact browser and version on your friend's machine, does it still display properly? I think the issue stems from issues with the mark-up...

Comment: The code displays correctly when I run it in Chrome on my home machine from my work server. When I use localhost on my home machine using chrome to run the file, it will not display.

Comment: Have you tried linking to the Google CDN versions of [jQuery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js) and [jQuery UI](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js)?

Comment: can you open firebug and and check in the error console that you don't have any errors..

Comment: @johnny don't go in that direction that its not working on few browsers , there might be some problem in the code, if you are good at using firebug you can easliy fix your problem , open the scripts through firebug and start debugging them.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can define a different charset halfway through a document. In your head, you set the charset to charset=iso-8859-1, but in the body you have <meta charset="utf-8">. I don't know for sure if that's a problem, but it certainly seems like it could be.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from obvious disregard for HTML standard as pointed out already - the difference between your college machine and home machine could be because you're using a different browser or version.

Move all styles and scripts to the head. It's very likely it will work then.